# XAMPP mail пишет, что почта отправилась, но на деле нет

Tags: php, xampp, gmail

localhost XAMPP прога
В php.ini и в sendmail.ini стоит smtp.gmail.com, моя почта (на почте небезопасные приложения доступ включен, без 2этапной аунтефикации), пароль на гмаил аккаунт, порт 587, tls, всё прописано по госту, как говорится.
запускаю простую пхп страницу с таким кодом:

```
<?php
$receiver = "моя почта@gmail.com";
$subject = "Email Test via PHP using Localhost";
$body = "Hi, there...This is a test email send from Localhost.";
$sender = "From:sender email address here";

if(mail($receiver, $subject, $body, $sender)){
    echo "Email sent successfully to $receiver";
}else{
    echo "Sorry, failed while sending mail!";
}
?>
```

Всё скопипастено из https://www.codingnepalweb.com/configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost/ 
И мне пишет, что почта отправлена, но сообщение не приходит (в спаме тоже нету). В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Вот прямо так с адреса `sender email address here` и отправляете?

Comment: Уже исправил и стало From: моя почта@gmail.com, но ситуация не поменялась.

Comment: Вы не имеете права отправлять письма от имени чужого сервера, любой нормальный почтовик заблокирует такое поддельное письмо. В поле From должен указываться тот домен, который на самом деле принадлежит серверу, с которого отправляются письма

Comment: Но ведь в sendmail.ini есть и название почты и пароль к ней. А какой домен использовать? smtp.gmail.com? Но сервер, с которого я отправляю, локальный. Как ему может ещё и домен приднадлежать? Я запутался... поясните пж

Comment: «в sendmail.ini есть и название почты и пароль к ней» — На enSO пишут, что это так не работает https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776170

Comment: Ещё на enSO такое есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836282

Comment: Ну блин, там советуют phpmailer скачать, а я целый день боролся с SMTP connect() failed и не смог победить. Нихочу опять ;-;  спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Если вы хотите отправлять почту через сторонний сервер (gmail), то делать SMTP-подключение это единственный возможный вариант

Comment: Ок, буду пробовать завтра.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче используй phpmailer, composer не надо и без него всё отлично работает и если локальный хост то выруби антивирус, тогда SMTP failed наверняка пропадёт.